# Getting history events for just new messages?

Tags: gmail-api

I'd like to monitor a users gmail account for new messages and take an appropriate action. Is there a way to fetch the history events for just new messages but NOT for things like starring an email or changing its labels, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up using messages.list and storing the timestamp of the most recent message. Then on subsequent calls to messages.list I'd supply a query of "after:theMostRecentTimestampIKnowOf" to find new messages since the last time we synced.

Answer (score 1):

Another route I've seen done, is if you have the ability to add a filter (e.g. user's can do that, or use the Google Admin SDK for Google Apps users, or do it through HTML/DOM hacking) then you can simply setup a filter to apply a label to all new messages.  Then just messages.list(labelId=THAT_LABEL) when you do your polling (and remove it after you process them).

Comment: is calling messages.list on a label or on an inbox more or less efficient than history.list?

Comment: Calling messages.list(labelId=SOME_LABEL) where SOME_LABEL isn't on that many messages (e.g. you use it as a tag on work queue) then it should be quite efficient, presumably indexed in the backend just like the history log.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any ability now to filter history based on change type, though it's something that would be nice to provide at some point.

Comment: actually what if I just query messages.list with no query/label filter applied so I get all the messages, and I just remember the most recent message I've seen. Then the next time I look at messages.list I can just iterate through until I see the last message id I saw. That would give me all the "new" messages correct? This depends on messages.list having a guarantee that the messages are in time sorted desc order.

Comment: Yes, I believe that should work fine if using no labelId or other query for filtering...